# Check if column value is present in Dictionary Value

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

i want to check whether the `colval` item is present in `values` of -`dictionary`
If it is present than append the corresponding `key` of that value, else append the `colval` item.

**CODE**
This is what i did

```
colormap = []
for col in colval:
    for k,v in master_colors.items():
        for x in v:
            if col == x:
                 colormap.append(k)
            else:
                colormap.append(col)
```

But this gives me `len(colormap)` more than `1000` which in actual should be `45` which is the length of colval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that colormap.append(col) is in the innermost loop. For each colval value, it's iterating through every value in the master_colors dict and every time it doesn't match that particular value, it appends colval. Instead you need to wait until you iterate through the entire dict and confirm that there's no match for the current colval value. Only then should you append that colval value.

Also, the way you've written it now, it's case-sensitive. If you change both strings you're comparing to lowercase (as below), it works fine.

```
colormap = []
for col in colval:
    match = False
    for k,v in master_colors.items():
        for x in v:
            if col.lower() == x.lower():
                colormap.append(k)
                match = True
        
    if not match:
        colormap.append(col)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of last (most inner) *for* loop you should test if color is in a list. And if so then break the second loop.

```
colormap = []
for col in colval:
    for k,v in master_colors.items():
        if col.lower() in v:
            colormap.append(k)
            break
    colormap.append(col)
```

Comment: I already tried not working ..gives `900` items it should be `45` only

Comment: yeah, needed to add a break, test it, now works, 64 items at the end